# Thread is successful from one button but not from another

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, sqlite

I'm writing a C# database program and I want to implement some threads in there. I got button on the form and in that button I start a thread which will save data from form to the database.

It works pretty well. Code of thread:

```
T1 = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
{
   UlozHlasovanie();               
});
```

Method code:

```
private void UlozHlasovanie()
    {
        string insert="insert into hlasovanie values (null, (select max(id) from VZ), '"+otazka+"')";
        var sql=new SQLiteCommand(insert,spoj);
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)//*
        {
            switch (row.Cells["rozhodnutie"].Value.ToString())
            {
                case "Za":
                    insert = "insert into hlasovanierec values (null, " + row.Cells["IDPODDET"].Value + " , (select max(id) from VZ), (select max(id) from hlasovanie), 1)"; 
                    break;
                case "Proti":
                    insert = "insert into hlasovanierec values (null, " + row.Cells["IDPODDET"].Value + " , (select max(id) from VZ), (select max(id) from hlasovanie), 2)"; 
                    break;
                case "Zdrzal sa":
                    insert = "insert into hlasovanierec values (null, " + row.Cells["IDPODDET"].Value + " , (select max(id) from vZ), (select max(id) from hlasovanie), 3)"; 
                    break;
            }                
            sql=new SQLiteCommand(insert,spoj);
            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }              
    }
```

Now the question. When I call it from one button, then it works perfectly. but when I call it from another button (which is still on the same form) it throws this (on asterix statement):

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Why does it work from one button and doesn't work from another? and how to make it to works from both buttons? Thanks for any answer ondro

edit:

call of thread that works

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        T1 = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            UlozHlasovanie();               
        });

        switch (krok)
        {
            case 1:
                ...
                break;

            case 2:
               ...              
                break;

        ...

            case 5:
                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = false;
                panel3.Visible = false;
                panel4.Visible = false;
                panel5.Visible = false;
                panel6.Visible = false;
                panel7.Visible = true;

                T1.Name = "sd";
                T1.Start();
                //while (!T1.IsAlive); 

                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = false;
                panel3.Visible = false;
                panel4.Visible = false;
                panel5.Visible = false;
                panel6.Visible = true;
                panel7.Visible = false;

                button1.Visible = false;
                break;

        }
```

non working call:

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        T1 = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            UlozHlasovanie();
        });
        T1.Name = "asd";
        T1.Start();
        //while (!T1.IsAlive);

        krok = 4;
        panel1.Visible = false;
        panel2.Visible = false;
        panel3.Visible = false;
        panel4.Visible = true;
        panel5.Visible = false;
        panel6.Visible = false;
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells["rozhodnutie"].Value = null;
        }
    }
```

Exception details:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   Source="urbar"
>   StackTrace:
>   at allin.noveVZ.UlozHlasovanie() in C:\Documents and Settings\ondro\My Documents\Dropbox\urbar\noveVZ.cs:line 485
>   at allin.noveVZ.b__9() in C:\Documents and Settings\ondro\My Documents\Dropbox\urbar\noveVZ.cs:line 506
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: please show the complete code that reproduces the problem

Comment: switch (row.Cells["rozhodnutie"].Value.ToString())

Comment: Most propably, `row.Cells["rozhodnutie"]` is null. Debug your code.

Comment: how to debug threads? breakpoints as usual?

Comment: Yes, it could be that there are no results or that the column is named differently.

Comment: Yay, SQL injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: I don't think this is a threading problem...

Comment: thanks, i know about sql injection, but i have to try it to see if it works, i will secure code later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As write L.B in comment, the column of datagridview was null. Thats was my mistake (code below), i throught the thread code will execute faster that ui-thread code. Adding while statement will handle this problem and i got loading gif there while thread is running.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    T1 = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
    {
        UlozHlasovanie();
    });
    T1.Name = "asd";
    T1.Start();
    while (T1.IsAlive) { Application.DoEvents(); }
    krok = 4;
    panel1.Visible = false;
    panel2.Visible = false;
    panel3.Visible = false;
    panel4.Visible = true;
    panel5.Visible = false;
    panel6.Visible = false;
    richTextBox1.Text = "";
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells["rozhodnutie"].Value = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're accessing the UI from another thread and this is not allowed, although I've seen cases were it randomly worked. You can get the grid data in the thread by calling `Invoke`, but here for simplicity you should consider getting the grid data before you start the thread and do only the sql command in the thread which usually takes more time.

Comment: i know about that ui stuff but how its possible that it "randomly" works every time with that one button?

Comment: But that would give an error like `Cross-thread operation not valid!` not `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @L.B you're absolutely right, however as I already wrote, I've seen cases were it randomly worked and when it didn't you don't always get the mentioned exception, and sometimes the UI just don't respond. If you want to eliminate the cross-thread effect, you'd better do it by the rules and then see if you get the same exception again.